# Docker volumes + mongodb (-v) - how to make them to work in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, mongodb, docker, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to create mongodb container:

```
docker run --name mydb -d -p 27017:27999 -e MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=mydb -v /myproject/dbtest:/data/db -v /myproject/docker/mongodb:/etc/mongod mongo:3.6.5-jessie --config /etc/mongod/mongo.conf
```

I have a problem with the -v flag: no matter what I'm trying it's not mapping my \myproject\dbtest and \myproject\docker\mongodb folders.

I'm trying to create a docker container for my project. Since that I already have a working mongod in my system then I want to map it into a different port (27999).

I tried also creating it using a docker file:

```
FROM mongo:3.6.5-jessie
ADD mongod.conf /etc/mongod.conf
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/mongod","--config","/etc/mongod.conf"]
```

This time it managed to find the configuration but I can't managed to connect into the db from outside of the container.

I tried:

```
127.0.0.1:2799
<the docker ip of the container>:27017
<the docker ip of the container>:27999
```

Here's my mongod.conf:

```
storage:
  dbPath: /data/db
  journal:
    enabled: true

systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo
```

Anyone managed to find out how to make it to work in Windows 10?
I'm using Docker CE v18.0.3

Comment: Do you mean you are having two containers my-project and mangodb? and you need to mount the volume (shared folder) in between two containers?

Comment: I just created a simple node.js code to test the container:

    import mongoose from 'mongoose'
    mongoose.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true})

Comment: Part of the solution:

    docker run --name mydb -d -p 27999:27017 -e MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=mydb mongo:3.6.5-jessie --ip_bind 0.0.0.0